# Alternate solution to create xml string

Tags: android, android-xml, android-ksoap2

I calling the .net `SOAP` web service from android by building Input `XML` and sending as a request. Receiving responds as a `XML` string and parsing it. All the above working fine.

For building the XML string i'm following the method using `DocumentBuilderFactory` example like this

```
DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();

Element rootElement = document.createElement("XMLINPUT");//Parent Node of the xml
document.appendChild(rootElement);

Element childElementCNN = document.createElement("CNNREFF");//Child Node
rootElement.appendChild(childElementCNN);
childElementCNN .appendChild(document.createTextNode(strCNN));

Element childElementCTT = document.createElement("CTTREFF");//Child Node
rootElement.appendChild(childElementCTT);
childElementCTT.appendChild(document.createTextNode(strCTT));

TransformerFactory factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = factory.newTransformer();
Properties outFormat = new Properties();
outFormat.setProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
outFormat.setProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
outFormat.setProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "no");
outFormat.setProperty(OutputKeys.VERSION, "1.0");
outFormat.setProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
transformer.setOutputProperties(outFormat);
DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document.getDocumentElement());
OutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(output);
transformer.transform(domSource, result);
String strInputXML = output.toString(); //Storing into a string
```

I want to know for building XML in android, because i want to use the same function to build different XML. Is there any other alternate solution? If there please post your answer.

Comment: Yes. Beside that, do you actually have a question?

Comment: @njzk2 yes i need a alternate solution to build xml string.

Comment: @njzk2 So please post any one that your aware of.

Comment: depends on what reason you have of changing. code simplicity ? portability to other platform ? performance ? lulz ? i don't understand why you need another solution. can't you just use the one you posted ?

Comment: @njzk2 I needed a simple code because i have to build a bigger xml more than 5 times. So i required a common method for all. nonetheless the above method works, but the code can't be reused; thats my prob

Comment: @njzk2 What for you asked this many questions? Post your answer.

Comment: the answer kinda depends on precision you could bring by answering my so many questions. I just try to understand your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, take a look at [SimpleXML](http://simple.sourceforge.net)

You can define beans according to your XML document structure and use getters / setters to manipulate values.

```
@Root(name = "XMLINPUT")
class MyBean {

    @Element(name = "CNNREFF")
    private String child1;

    @Element(name = "CTTREFF")
    private String child2;


}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I try with your answer.